# find the coefficients of $\frac{1}{x+k}$ in the summation

Tags: binomial-theorem

i am able to prove the identity by putting the value of $A_n$ but cannot find it directly.I need help in finding the coefficents.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\Large 13.\pars{\mrm{i}}:}$

- Multiply both members by $\pars{x + k}$:
  \begin{align}
  &{n! \over x\ldots \pars{x + k - 1}\pars{x + k + 1}
  \ldots\pars{x + n}}
  \\[2mm] = &\
  A_{k} +
  \pars{x + k}\sum_{\substack{j = 0 \\ j \not= k}}^{n}{A_{j} \over x + j}
  \end{align}
- Takes the limit $\ds{x \to - k}$:
  \begin{align}
  &{n! \over \pars{-k}\ldots \pars{- 1}\pars{1}
  \ldots\pars{-k + n}} = A_{k}
  \\[5mm]
  & A_{k} = {n! \over k!\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{n - k}!} =
  \bbx{\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}} \\ &
  \end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large 13.\pars{\mrm{ii}}:}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}{1 \over
\pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{t^{k} - t^{k + 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-t}^{k} -
t\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-t}^{k}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n + 1}\,\dd t = \bbx{1 \over n + 2} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks but i got it last night

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Thanks. It's a nice problem.